# Set adMob ads to the edge of the screen?

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I've seen a lot of apps have ads at the edge of the screen. But when I'm trying to put ads at the absolute edge of the layout, it automatically places it a few dp apart from the edge.

This is the XML:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, MY_DEVICE_ID"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="MY_DEV_CODE" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

**Full XML code:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tBtn1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tBtn1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tBtn1"
    android:text="Record as long as the button is touched" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/tBtn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOff="Off"
    android:textOn="On" />

<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/recButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Chronometer"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, MY_DEVICE_ID"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="MY_DEV_ID" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/recButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/record_btn" />
```

Comment: have you tried layout_alignParentLeft="true"?

Comment: do you have margins or Insets for the parent-view?

Comment: @WEBALDO.at No, I've just posted the whole XML code, for the whole layout. You can check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And that's the matter:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Don't use a padding of the Parent-view for the padding bottom and it will work.

Comment: Ohhhh, so that's what you meant, I'm new to android programming :) thanks a lot!